# Angularjs Getting error when trying to call method from a service i defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning Angularjs and i'm trying to create a service to do common tasks that need to be done for all my controllers.

I'm currently getting the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'getAuthHeader' of undefined
```

app.js

```
var token = "mytoken"
var baseUrl = "mybaseUrl";

var myezteam = angular.module('myezteam', ['ui.bootstrap']);

myapp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/profile', 
            {
                controller: 'ProfileController',
                templateUrl: 'template.html'
            })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/profile'});
});

// This gets the basic information that is needed for every page
myapp.service('base', function() {

    this.getAuthHeader = function($http) {
        // Set authorization token so we know the user has logged in.
        return $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
    }
});
```

profile.js

```
 myapp.controller('ProfileController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http, base) {

        base.getAuthHeader($http);  // <-- THIS LINE IS THROWING THE ERROR
    }]);
```

Why is the error occurring and how can I fix it? Also, is there a way to setup a config on my app so that I don't need to call `base.getAuthHeader($http);` in every controller, but it will automatically get called when every controller is loaded?

Comment: Why do you pass `$http` around like that? Looks confusing... Dependency Injection works in services as well.

Comment: @elclanrs Can you elaborate? I'm brand new to AngularJS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not injecting your service `base` into your controller.  You need to inject it in the same way you did with `$scope` and `$http`

```
myapp.controller('ProfileController', ['$scope', '$http', 'base', 
    function($scope, $http, base) { ... });
```

Comment: That took the error away. Do you have an answer for the second part of my question?`is there a way to setup a config on my app so that I don't need to call base.getAuthHeader($http); in every controller, but it will automatically get called when every controller is loaded?`

Comment: Do you want to check if the user is logged in and if not redirect them somewhere?

Comment: Yea, but i haven't gotten that far yet. For now i'm just curious if I can set some method calls in a config or something.

Comment: Check out the `resolve` method of the config.  You can alter your `base` method to return a promise and resolve if the user meets your logged in requirement, else you can reject and then redirect the user to a log in page.